# How to remove X-Frame-Options from fastify response?

Tags: typescript, cors, fastify

I absolutely need to serve a PDF from a web service running Fastify. However the browser complains about a cross-origin issue since the PDF is served from a different subdomain.

In other words: `https://confirm.domain.com` (React app) uses [pdfObject](https://pdfobject.com/) to load a PDF from `https://pdf.domain.com` (Fastify Web service), but the PDF does not download because the fastify server returns a `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`.

I have installed the [`@fastify/cors`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors) package on the Fastify server, and have setup the CORS plugin as

```
await server.register(cors, { 
   origin: [
      /\.domain\.com/,
   ]
});
```

Then I have added two headers to the route :

```
// -- following line does not work --
//reply.removeHeader('X-Frame-Options')

return reply.code(200)
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'https://confirm.domain.com')
  .header('Content-disposition', `filename=${documentName}`)                  
  //   -- following line does not work --
  //.header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW-FROM https://confirm.domain.com')
  .type('application/pdf')
  .send(buffer);
```

Now, when I navigate to `https://pdf.domain.com`, I can see the PDF just fine. But when I try to get that PDF through `pdfObject`, I get `pdf.domain.com refuse to connect`.

Inspecting the network request, I see `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` in the response headers.

In other words, browsing to `https://pdf.domain.com/` displays the PDF, however this fails with a refusal to display the content because of the `X-Frame-Options` response header:

```html
<iframe src="https://pdf.domain.com" />
```

How do I remove this response header?

**NOTE:** I only use the `@fastify/cors` module, no frame guard, no helmet, as both explicitly add what I specifically try to remove.

Comment: Can you confirm you're not using security libraries like [fastify-helmet](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-helmet) or [fastify-frame-guard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-frame-guard)?

Comment: @JeffBowman I have confirmed it, I am not using any other plugin than CORS. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but [fastify-cors#48](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors/issues/48) does show a very straightforward setup that does specify SAMEORIGIN for X-Frame-Options. So it does seem like this isn't specific to your setup.